# How do I get CircularProgressIndicator for the .pop()

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

The onTap waits for the pics and docs to get uploaded then it pops the page. but I want it to show a cicularProgressIndicator on top of everything and the user gets a message to wait until the onTap is finished.

```dart
onTap: () async {
                    if (image11 != null) {
                      await uploadImage1(image11);
                    }
                    await firestor.add({
                      "Doc": docs.text,
                      "gear": gear.text,
                      "price": price.text,
                      "1stpic": imageUrl1,
                    
                    });
                  await Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onTap: () async {
  openloadingdialog(context);
  if (image11 != null) {
    await uploadImage1(image11);
  }
  await firestor.add({
    "Doc": docs.text,
    "gear": gear.text,
    "price": price.text,
    "1stpic": imageUrl1,
           
   });
   Navigator.pop(context);
   await Navigator.pop(context);
 },

 openloadingdialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      useRootNavigator: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            return false;
          },
          child: AlertDialog(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor,
            content: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: cant use 'await' on the second .pop;  "his expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used."  @SHASHI KUMAR